# Run a vbscript from another vbscript

Tags: vbscript

How do I get a vbscript to run another vbscript?

Id imagine its only a few lines of code but not tried doing this before, nothing is passed between the 2, one just needs to call/run the other.

For examples the script being run is called TestScript.vbs, the other script for it to call/run would be called Secondscript.vbs, both of which are located in C:\Temp.

Thanks
Mark

Comment: I know that its do able with a .bat but is there not also a way to do it within the actual script?

Comment: Try This Like : `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "Your-VBScript-Here"`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

See if the following works

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objShell.Run "TestScript.vbs" 

' Using Set is mandatory
Set objShell = Nothing
```

Comment: Tried this, variable undefined, do I need to add a declaration for it as well?

Comment: Ignore my original response - it was garbage.  Hopefully the above will solve your issue.

Comment: The problem with this approach is it assumes that `.vbs` is associated with Windows Scripting Host (`cscript.exe` or `wscript.exe`).

Answer (score 14):

You can try using the Wshshell.Run method which gives you little control of the process you start with it. Or you could use the WshShell.Exec method which will give you control to terminate it, get a response, pass more parameters (other than commandline args), get status, and others

To use Run (Simple Method)

```
Dim ProgramPath, WshShell, ProgramArgs, WaitOnReturn,intWindowStyle
Set WshShell=CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
ProgramPath="c:\test run script.vbs"
ProgramArgs="/hello /world"
intWindowStyle=1
WaitOnReturn=True
WshShell.Run Chr (34) & ProgramPath & Chr (34) & Space (1) & ProgramArgs,intWindowStyle, WaitOnReturn
```

**ProgramPath** is the full path to your script you want to run 
**ProgramArgs** is the arguments you want to pass to the script. (NOTE: the arguments are separated by a space, if you want to use an argument that contains a space then you will have to enclose that argument in quotes [Safe way to do this is use **CHR (34)** Example `ProgramArgs= chr (34) & "/Hello World" & chr (34)`])
**IntWindowStyle** is the integer that determines how the window will be displayed. More info on this and WaitOnReturn can be found here [WshShell.Run Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)
**WaitOnReturn** if true then the script will pause until the command has terminated, if false then the script will continue right after starting command.

*NOTE: The Run method can return the exit code but you must set WaitOnReturn to True, and assign the 'WshShell.Run' to a variable. (EX: `ExitCode=WshShell.Run (Command,intWindowStyle,True)`)*

To Use EXEC (Advanced Method)

```
Dim ProgramPath, WshShell, ProgramArgs, Process, ScriptEngine
Set WshShell=CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
ProgramPath="c:\test run script.vbs"
ProgramArgs="/hello /world"
ScriptEngine="CScript.exe"
Set Process=WshShell.Exec (ScriptEngine & space (1) & Chr(34) & ProgramPath & Chr (34) & Space (1) & ProgramArgs)
Do While Process.Status=0
    'Currently Waiting on the program to finish execution.
    WScript.Sleep 300
Loop
```

**ProgramPath** same as Run READ RUN'S DESCRIPTION
**ProgramArgs** DITTO 
**ScriptEngine** The Engine you will be using for executing the script. since the exec method requires a win32 application, you need to specify this. Usually either "WScript.exe" or "CScript.exe". Note that in order to use stdin and stdout (we'll cover what these are a bit further down) you must choose "CScript.exe".
**Process** this is the Object that references to the program the script will start. It has several members and they are: ExitCode, ProcessID, Status, StdErr, StdIn, StdOut, Terminate.

*More Details about the members of Process Object*

1. **ExitCode** This is the exit code that is returned when the process terminates.
2. **ProcessID** This is the ID that is assigned to the process, every process has an unique processID.
3. **Status** This is a code number that indicates the status of the process, it get set to '-1' when the process terminates.
4. **StdErr** This is the object that represents the Standard Error Stream
5. **StdIn** This is the Object that represents the Standard Input Stream, use it to write additional parameters or anything you want to pass to the script you are calling. (`Process.StdIn.WriteLine "Hello Other Worlds"`)
6. **StdOut** This is the Object that represents the Standard Output Stream, It is *READONLY* so you can use `Process.StdOut.ReadLine`. This is the stream that the called script will receive any information sent by the calling script's stdin. If you used the stdin's example then StdOut.Readline will return "Hello Other Worlds". If there is nothing to read then the script will hang while waiting for an output. meaning the script will appear to be *Not Responding*
      *Note: you can use `Read` or `ReadAll` instead of `ReadLine` if you want. Use `Read (X)` if you want to read X amount of characters. Or `ReadAll` if you want the rest of the stream.*
7. **Terminate** Call this method to force terminate the process.

*For more information about WshShell.Exec go to [Exec Method Windows Scripting Host](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)*

Answer (score 12):

Just to complete, you could send 3 arguments like this:

```
objShell.Run "TestScript.vbs 42 ""an arg containing spaces"" foo"
```

Comment: Thanks, blairxy -- that was the bit of info I came looking for.

Answer (score 11):

You can also load the body of the script and execute it within the same process:

```vb
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fs.OpenTextFile("script2.vbs")
body = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
Execute body
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you don't want to get mad with spaces in arguments and want to use variables try this:

```
objshell.run "cscript ""99 Writelog.vbs"" /r:" &  r & " /f:""" & wscript.scriptname & """ /c:""" & c & ""
```

where

```
r=123
c="Whatever comment you like"
```

Comment: The only approach here that makes sense and doesn't mislead due to file associations.

Answer (score 2):

I saw the below code working.
Simple, but I guess not documented.
Anyone else used the 'Execute' command ?

```
   Dim body, my_script_file
   Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


   Set my_script_file = fso.OpenTextFile(FILE)
   body = my_script_file.ReadAll
    my_script_file.Close

    Execute body
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
Option Explicit

On error resume next
Dim Shellobj
Set Shellobj = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Shellobj.Run "Test.vbs" 

Set Shellobj = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Martin's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1686474/2605073) didn't work at all for me ("File not found") and [atesio's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14235931/2605073) does not allow to call two scripts which include repeating variable definitions, here is another alternative which finally worked for me:

```
filepath =  Chr(34) & "C:\...\helloworld.vbs" & Chr(34)
Set objshell= CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
objshell.Run "wscript " & filepath, , True
Set objshell= Nothing
```

(Windows 8.1)

Comment: Pretty sure [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18734399/692942) covered it.