# Call another vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have a vbscript file A that will call another vbscript file B. File B requires arguments and it is located in the same folder with file A.

The code works like this:

1. File A.vbs is located in C:\temp
2. In File A, call C:\temp\B.vbs

Wherever folder I put these vbs files, as long as they are on the same folder, file A should call file B without changing the code. How can I do this in VBScript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run a vbscript from another vbscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686454/run-a-vbscript-from-another-vbscript)

Comment: You'd put a comment under my answer that the relative path didn't work, so I added an alternative solution, though that comment has been deleted now, but I'll leave the alternative one in just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the question is but it sounds like you're wondering how you know what path to use. If so, I think that it should just work with a relative path like `.\B.vbs`.

Otherwise if the question is how do you execute one script from another, look at [Shell.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

So all put together, something like `WshShell.Run ".\B.vbs arg1 arg2"` should work I think.

Edit: If the relative path doesn't work, just use `WScript.ScriptFullName` to get the path of the currently executing script as:

```
WshShell.Run Replace(WScript.ScriptFullName, WScript.ScriptName, "") & "B.vbs arg1 arg2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim aShell
Set aShell = CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
aShell.Run "B.vbs"
Set aShell = Nothing
```